# Replace all row values according to a value in a specific column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Let's say that we have a dataset that look like this:

| var | c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| b | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE |
| c | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| d | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE |

I want to replace all the row values (right wise not the var column) according to the FALSE value of column c1 with NA.

Ideally I want to look like this :

| var | c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| b | FALSE | NA | NA |
| c | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| d | FALSE | NA | NA |

```
var  = c("a","b","c","d") 
c1 = c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
c2 = c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)
c3 = c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)
data= tibble(var,c1,c2,c3);data
```

How can I do it in R using the dplyr package ?
Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `across` in `dplyr` - loop `across` the 'c2', 'c3' columns, and use the logical column from 'c1' to return the values of the column, by default the last condition i.e. `TRUE` will be all `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>% 
   mutate(across(c2:c3, ~ case_when(c1 ~ .x)))
```

-output

```
data
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  var   c1    c2    c3   
  <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 a     TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
2 b     FALSE NA    NA   
3 c     TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
4 d     FALSE NA    NA
```